# Is the group cohomology for a profinite group always torsion?

Tags: group-cohomology, profinite-groups

In his notes on group cohomology [here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~roblot/ihp/weakmw.pdf), Bjorn Poonen claims that $H^i(G, A)$ is torsion when $G$ is profinite and $i>0$. why is the following not a counterexample? Take $G= \hat{\Bbb Z}$, and $A=\Bbb Z$ with the trivial $G$ action, so that $H^1(G,A)$ is just $Hom_{cont} (G, A)$. Then we have a the element $f: G \rightarrow A$ given by $f(1)=1$. This extends to a function on $G$ because $1$ is a topological generator. This should have infinite order in $H^1(G,A)$, unless I'm mistaken. If someone can help clear this up it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Zhen Lin's answer is right. A clarification -- it's true that a map out of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is determined by where $1$ goes, but it's not true that $1$ can go anywhere; a necessary and sufficient condition is that the image of $1$ be topologically nilpotent, i.e. if $f: \mathbb{\widehat{Z}} \to G$ and $1 \mapsto g$ then the sequence $g^n$ should converge to the identity.

Comment: @hunter : how would you show that $H^i(G, A)$ is a torsion abelian group for $i>0$, however? A continuous map $f : G^i \to A$ has a finite image, so we would be done it $f$ is a homomorphism (true for $i=1$ and $A$ is a trivial $G$-module), but otherwise… ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such continuous homomorphism $f : \hat{\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, since we are giving $\mathbb{Z}$ the discrete topology, $\ker f$ must be an open subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. But open subgroups of profinite groups have finite index, so the image of $f : \hat{\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbb{Z}$ must be finite, hence $f = 0$.

In particular, $H^1 (\hat{\mathbb{Z}}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

Comment: Right, thank you this makes much more sense. Then since it is compact, open subgroups have finite index, so it factors through some finite group and is thus torsion. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, any continuous homomorphism from a profinite group to a discrete group must factor through a finite subgroup.