# Why is the group cohomology for a profinite group always torsion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, torsion-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group, $A$ be a discrete $G$-module, and $n>0$ be an integer.

> Why is the cohomology group $H^n(G;A)$ a torsion abelian group?

Here $H^n$ denotes the continuous cohomology groups. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159841) thread is related, but I didn't find the answer to my question.

— I know that any (continuous) cocycle $f : G^n \to A$ has finite image, for $G$ is compact and $A$ is discrete. If the subgroup generated by the image of $f$ inside $A$ is also finite (say of cardinality $k$), then $k \cdot f = 0 : G^n \to A$ so that the class of $f$ in $H^n(G;A)$ has order at most $k$. 
If $f$ is also a group morphism, which holds if $n=1$ and $A$ is a trivial $G$-module, then the image of $f$ inside $A$ is already a subgroup, so the aforementioned condition is satisfied.

– But in general, we only want to find a multiple of $f$ which is a coboundary (without this multiple to be the zero map itself, as it was the case above). I'm not sure how to proceed. Is there may a smarter way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a direct limit of cohomology groups for finite groups.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : I agree. Say $G$ is a finite group. Then why would $[f] \in H^n(G, A)$ have finite order? In fact, I don't see why the values taken by $f$ have finite order in $A$.

Comment: When $G$ is finite, $H^n(G,A)$ is $|G|$-torsion when $n>0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : thank you for your comment. But this doesn't mean that $|G| \cdot f$ is the zero map for any cocycle $f : G^n \to A$, does it ? So, what would be the easiest way for proving that $H^n(G;A)$ has torsion?

Comment: No, it means that $|G|\cdot f$ is a coboundary. The theorem is in all the textbooks: restriction of cohomology to a subgroup composed with corestriction back gives multiplication by the index. This is the case with the trivial subgroup.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : Thank you! I will look at this more carefully.

Comment: This is stated as COROLLARY II.4.3 in Milne's notes on class field theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Res}{\mathrm{Res}}
\newcommand{\Cor}{\mathrm{Cor}}$

- First of all, we can assume that $G$ is finite of order $m$. Indeed, by the proof of proposition 2.2.16 in [Sharifi's notes](http://math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/groupcoh.pdf), we deduce that for any cocycle $f : G^r \to A$ (with $r \geq 0$), the cohomology class $[f] \in H^r(G,A)$ belongs to the image of the inflation map $H^r(G/N, A^N) \to H^r(G,A)$ for some open normal subgroup $N \leq G$.
  In particular, $[f]$ is a torsion element if $H^r(G/N, A^N)$ is a torsion group. Since the group $G/N$ is finite ($G$ is compact and $N$ is open), it is sufficient to prove that $H^r(G', A)$ is a torsion group whenever $G'$ is a finite group and $r>0$.
- Actually, we are going to show that $H^r(G, A)$ has finite exponent, namely its exponent is $m = |G|$.
  When $r \geq 0$, the composition 
  $$\Cor \circ \Res : H^r(G,A) \to H^r(\{1\}, A) \to H^r(G,A)$$
  is the multiplication by $m = [G : \{1\}]$ in the cohomology group $H^r(G,M)$. This is proved in prop. II.1.30 in Milne's [Class Field Theory notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf#page=76) ; here we are using the fact that $G$ is finite.
- Because $r > 0$, we have $H^r(\{1\}, A) = 0$. In particular, the composition $\Cor \circ \Res$ has to be the zero map.
  Since it is also the multipication by $m$, this implies that $$m H^r(G,A) = 0,$$ whenever $r>0$ and $G$ is a finite group of order $m$.
  This concludes the proof.