# Vanishing of second Galois cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field, galois-cohomology

This most likely follows from a standard result but a lack of knowledge prevents me from seeing this.

Let $K$ be a non Archimedean local field. Let $\Gamma$ be $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$. Let $T$ be a torus over $k$. Then define $\mathrm{X}(T)= \mathrm{Hom}(T,\mathbb{G}_{m})$ and this has a continuous $\Gamma$ action. Further let  $\mathrm{X}(T)_{\mathbb{Q}} =  \mathrm{X}(T) \otimes _{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}$.

Then why is $\mathrm{H^{2}}(\Gamma, \mathrm{X}(T)_{\mathbb{Q}})$ trivial. Is it because $\mathrm{X}(T)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is an injective $\Gamma$ module?
Any reference will be helpful.

Comment: I think it follows from the following more general fact. Let $\Gamma$ be a profinite group, let $M$ be a discrete $\Gamma$-module. Then $\mathrm{H}^{i}(\Gamma,M)$ are torsion for all $i > 0$. See Serre, "Galois Cohomology", Section 2.2, Corollary 3 (or google "profinite cohomology torsion").

Comment: @MinseonShin That does the job, thanks :)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2430528/